# CDI: Injecting resources to beans from external libraries

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

In Spring we have annotation-based and XML-based configuration. While the first is recommended for quick development, the second is more flexible and able to handle special cases. By us there are currently 2: injecting mocks for JUnit tests and configuring beans from external libraries.

I haven't found any equivalent for XML configuration for CDI, so my question is, how to handle dependency injection for such beans? They are from external libraries, they need to be configured and there's no possibility to add any annotations to them.

Comment: The latter case (external beans) sounds like they intentionally made it dependent on Spring. Any examples on such libraries?

Comment: @Kayaman thousands of them, practically everything what was not intentionally made for CDI, such as Velocity, GSON, CSVParser and many more, everything that is a class that requires any configuration and/or setting some other class within.

Comment: Well that's just not true. While DI is a handy way of doing configuration, it's not the only way. Of course if you're used to Spring, you might not realize the other ways.

Comment: @Kayaman well, I'm aware of non-IoC configuration, this is why I want to use only IoC. A great trauma for me is the Singleton-madness-pattern, followed by code for managing JDBC connection copied into each bean :( So, the only alternative I can accept should involve configuring and producing classes in single point.

Comment: You can use the @@Produces annotation have a single point of configuration. Then @@Inject the produced item, whatever it may be, into any and all beans that require it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have three solutions to your need:

### Use a producer

CDI provides a way to transform non CDI class in beans. It is called a producer. If you want to create a bean from a class named `NonCdiClass` You only have to create something like that

```
public class MyProducers {
    @Produces
    public NonCdiClass produceNonCdiClass() {
        return new NonCdiClass();
        };
    }
  }
```

You can now `@Inject` this bean when needed.

You can put as many producer method as you want in your class.

If you need to simulate injection in your produced bean you can do it thanks to CDI that injects parameters in producer methods calls.

```
@Produces
public NonCdiClass produceNonCdiClass(MyFisrtBean param1, MySecondBean param2) {
    NonCdiClass res = new NonCdiClass(param1);
    res.setParam(param2);
    return res;
    };
}
```

In this example `MyFirstBean` and `MySecondBean` are existing bean classes that will be injected by CDI at producing time.

Producers can also have Qualifiers (on them or on their parameters) or inject the `InjectionPoint` which is a CDI internal bean allowing you to produce your bean differently in function of where is the injection and what annotation it has.

You have a nice `InjectionPoint` example in [Weld reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.1.5.Final/en-US/html_single/#d0e1624).

### Develop an extension

I won't go into much details here since I don't know if it's your need, but you can register bean in an extension in the AfterBeanValidation phase. These registered beans can be of any class you want.
Should you need more info I could develop here.

### Use Seam Solder (legacy) or wait for Deltaspike 0.6

Solder integrated a [config module](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/solder/latest/reference/en-US/html_single/#part4) but this project is no more maintained since it's been in the process to be merged in [Apache Deltaspike](http://deltaspike.org). This merge is in Deltaspike roadmap for version 0.6: http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DELTASPIKE-271. So you could start using Solder config and switch to Deltaspike when it'll have the feature (which should be quite close).
This solution is not my favorite but if you really want to have a config file à la Spring, it's the closest solution

Comment: For the producer idea, is it possible to get an EntityManager to be injected like MyFirstBean and MySecondBean are? Just putting EntityManager doesn't work, if I add @PersistenceContext it doesn't compile.

Comment: No you can't inject an EntityManager as a producer param. However you can inject it in the Bean containing the producer method and use it in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Pure CDI provides the `@Alternative` annotation to inject for example mock objects during testing phase via `beans.xml`, but many mock libraries do a better work since they're designed for it.

I'm not aware of a way to use `beans.xml` to inject anything outside of the ear/war itself.

Comment: Oh, it would solve the problem with test things. But there is still problem with using pure java external libraries, not prepared to use with IoC.

Comment: Well, I don't agree with your notion that any library that requires configuration needs IoC. But I've done very little Spring and mostly standard Java EE, so it's not difficult to see why our views differ.